# How do I Install, Update, Register a Nuget package on the Web Server that does not have Nuget or Visual Studio installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

The code works fine on my development machine, but I get an error when I try running it on the server:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I understand that I need to install this assembly, but the directions to install it say to use Package Manager Console.

This is a server that isn't running anything but IIS.

I'm a contractor, so I don't want to the company and tell them that they have to buy Visual Studio for this server unless I really have to.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't just deploy the exe, deploy everything from the build.

Comment: @RobIII, so like copy the whole folder over?

Comment: Exactly, have you tried it? And what's up with the `_DEPRECATED` stuff?

Comment: Have you installed the .net core SDK? Dotnet command will not work if not installed.

Comment: @RobIII - the way this company seems to do their updates: They take the existing code, copy it to a DEPRECATED folder, and then manually copy over the changed files. It's like, why does Visual Studio even have a Publish feature when you can use the old Sneaker Network?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT it is an ASP.NET-MVC website. They have not gone to .NET Core yet. I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by manually copying over files that had recently changed in the project.

That would be the DLL in the `bin` folder, any of the *.cshtml files that were changed (as seen in the TFS Change History), and manually copy over any NuGet packages from my development PC to the web server.

For example: In the error posted in the original question, I simply located `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` in the packages folder of my PC and replaced that same existing file on the web server.

It doesn't seem like the preferred technique to me, but that's what this company has in place.